# Cake PHP does not find my model

Tags: php, cakephp

So my test page works on my localhost, but as soon as I took the project to a webhost I get the problem:

```
Error: Class 'Guest' not found
File:/home/www/my-test-domain.co.za/Test/app/Controller/TestController.php
Line: 14
```

This is my model:

[image: Model]

This is my controller:

[image: Controller]

The DB connection is fine (CakePHP indicated that it is) and I have no idea what to try next. I have probably tried every combination of typing the word "Guest" with and without capital letters throughout the project. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Nitpicker's note: `var` belongs to the legacy PHP4 OO syntax. You should considering completely migrating to PHP5 syntax. Same with `&new`.

Comment: Are you aware that `var` is relic from PHP4? In modern PHP you should not encounter them. Also, I would like to not that `var` is an equivalent of `public`, which would mean that not only you are using an ancient syntax, but also - you are breaking the basic object encapsulation. FYI: **PHP 5.0.0 was released in 2004th**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Files should be named after the class they contain. Your class is called `Guest` so your file should be `Guest.php`. However, the screen-shot suggests the name is `guest.php` (please note the lowercase).

If it works in your development box, you're probably using Windows.

Comment: Wow, what a fine eye. That was the problem! I am using windows.. and the server is probably Linux. Would've been the last thing I would think of. Changing the file to capital letters worked!